# Java DB new record inserting in wrowng row

Tags: java, database

I am trying to instert new items to the table but they don't inserting to the last row.
They inserting where they want. For explaple, they can instert 30 rows above last one.
The funny thing is that sometimes works fine, sometimes have that issue. I have tried to instert new row from netbeans-->services-->java DB-->my database, with the same issue.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public void doConnect()  {
   
    try{
        
        String host=fl.DataBaseFiles();
        String uName="tmimaIpologiston";
        String uPass="kyri";

        con=DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);
        
    }
    catch (SQLException err){
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, err.getMessage());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Πρέπει πρώτα να εννωθείτε με τη βάση δεδομένων.", "Connection Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        System.exit(0);
    }

  }


public void importToEF16DBassistantTest() {
   
    
    try {
        
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        
        stmt = ctd.con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        String sql = fl.selectAllFromEF16DBassistant();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        //kyria
        
        rs.moveToInsertRow();
        

        rs.updateInt("AE", Integer.parseInt(AEylikoy));
        rs.updateString("XRONIA", yearField.getText());
        rs.updateString("PALIOI_AE", AEpalioi);
        rs.updateString("MONADA", monada);
        rs.updateString("EF13", ef13);
        rs.updateString("IMEROMINIA_EF13", imerominiaEf13);
        rs.updateString("YLIKA", YlikoPane.getText());
        rs.updateString("SN", SNPane.getText());

        rs.updateString("KATASTASIOKAA", AAokField.getText());
        if (katastsiOKCheckBox.isSelected() == true) {
            ok = true;
        } else {
            ok = false;
        }
        rs.updateBoolean("OKBTN", ok);
        rs.updateString("KATASTASIPOEAA", AApoeField.getText());
        if (katastsiPOECheckBox.isSelected() == true) {
            poe = true;
        } else {
            poe = false;
        }
        rs.updateBoolean("POEBTN", poe);

        rs.updateString("EF157", EF157);
        rs.updateString("IMEROMINIA_EF157", EF157Imerominia);
        rs.updateString("AR_PRAKTIKOU", arithmosPraktikou);
        rs.updateString("ERGASIES", ergasies);
        rs.updateString("IMEROMINIA_ISODOU", imerominiaIsodou);
        rs.updateString("IMEROMINIA_PERAS_ERGASION", imerominiaPerasEpiskevis);
        rs.updateString("IMEROMINIA_EXODOU", imerominiaExodou);

       
        rs.insertRow();

        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        Logger.getLogger(EF16.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        
    }




    importFromEF16DBassistant();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tables in relational databases are inherently unordered.

This means that there is no "position" where it's inserted, it just gets added to the set of rows. In that sense tables behave a lot like a `Set` or a `Map` in Java: they don't have an order, just "a bunch of content".

If you want to return the values in some specific order, you must use `ORDER BY` to specify what value you want to sort them by in a given `SELECT`.

This applies to basically all relational databases and as such to almost anything you can access using JDBC/`java.sql`.